# Probability of winning a bet

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

I'm trying to solve the following problem : There is a man that bets $1$ dollar in a game. If he wins he leaves the table. If he loses he tries again, betting 2 dollars this time. **But if he loses a second time he quits the game.**

The chance of winning a round is $p=\frac{1}{2}$;

What is his winning chance?

I've argumented the following :  To win his first rounds the probability is $\frac{1}{2}$;

If he loses the first game , then he has to win the second one. So the probability would be $\frac{1}{2} \frac{1}{2} = \frac{1}{4}$;

And so, his winning probability would be $\frac{1}{2} +\frac{1}{4} = \frac{3}{4}$;

Is this the correct answer?

I'm thinking that there might be a trick in the middle, something like the Monty Hall problem because the man in the problem quits the bet if he loses twice.

Can someone offer some insight ? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you did the right calculation. The man ends up winning 1 dollar with probability 3/4 and losing 3 dollars with probability 1/4 (when he quits the table). The average return is 0 because this is a fair game. There is no extra information.

In the Monty Hall problem, the host of the game is the source of extra information. He knows where the prize is and always opens a door behind which there is a goat (no prize). The trick does not come from nowhere. It comes from the host's knowledge of which door has the prize.

Answer (score 1):

No trick that I can see -- that seems right.